# How can I extract the string sent with the ok to check it in unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

How can I extract the string sent with the ok to check it in test

```
  public IHttpActionResult PostConnect()
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(result.ToString())
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return BadRequest("An error");
        }
    }
```

I tried to do something but it didn't work

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void TestPostConnect()
    {
        var agentController = new Controller();
        IHttpActionResult actionResult = agentController.PostConnect();
        var okResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
    }
```

And how can I convert from string to json?

Comment: Check the `Value` property?

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed to what was expected.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assume in your test that it is an OkObjectResult, that's the main reason for tests. Meaning you should expect it to be of type OkObjectResult. After that you can use the Value property to retrieve the string.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestPostConnect()
{
    var agentController = new Controller();
    IHttpActionResult actionResult = agentController.PostConnect();
    var result = actionResult.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();
    result.Value.Should().BeOfType<string>();
    result.Value.Should().Be("your string");
}
```

Comment: He writes me on this line that there is an error:
"var result = actionResult.Should (). BeOfType <OkObjectResult> ();"

The seduction:
IHttpActionResult does not contain a definition of 'Should '

Comment: Add using FluentAssertions; at the top of your file and also add the package reference to it in your csproj. 
<PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="5.10.3" />